# If all composite of a function and a linear functional zero, then is the function zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and $R:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow A$ be a differentiable function.

If $\phi\circ R=0$ for all $\phi\in A^*$, then is $R$ necessarily zero?

Suppose $R$ is nonzero so that there exists $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $x:=R(z)\neq 0$. If there is a bounded linear functional $\phi$ such that $\phi(x)\neq 0$, then we are done. But how?

Comment: Don't you just need the fact that $A^*$ separates the points of $A$ ? (I.e. Hahn Banach)

Answer (score 0):

Assume there exist $z \in \Bbb C$ with $R(z) = v \ne 0$. Let $V = \langle v \rangle$. Define $\varphi : V \to \Bbb C$ by $\varphi (t v) = t \| v \|, \ \forall t \in \Bbb C$. Notice that $| \varphi (tv) | = |t| \| v \| = \| tv \|$. Using [the Hahn-Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem), there exist a linear extension $\tilde \varphi : A \to \Bbb C$ such that $\tilde \varphi \big| _V = \varphi$ and $| \tilde \varphi (a) | \le \| a \| \ \forall a \in A$ (which means that $\tilde \varphi$ is continuous). This means that $\tilde \varphi \in A^*$, and $\tilde \varphi (v) = \varphi (v) = \| v \| \ne 0$ (because $v \ne 0$ by assumption).

On the other hand, $\tilde \varphi (v) = (\tilde \varphi \circ R) (z) = 0 (z) = 0$, which contradicts the findings in the previous paragraph. Therefore, no such $z$ exists, so $R(z) = 0 \ \forall z \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Why is such a $\pi$ continuous?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: You are right, $\pi$ is continuous if and only if $V$ is closed - and it is not clear whether $V$ can be chosen to be closed. Let me think about this, please.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: The question whether, for given $v \ne 0$, there exist a *closed* algebraic complement is interesting but I do not know how to answer it. I have, therefore, changed the strategy of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I also suspected that Hahn-Banach would be necessary.